# Показать пользователю сколько средств он потратил (total spend)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

Как вывести в карточке клиента сумму всех его заказов (total spend)
Задача присваивать клиенту скидку, основываясь на его потраченых средствах, есть несколько уровней, например за 1000р скидка 3%, за 5000р скидка 5% и т.д.
А также показывать клиенту сколько ему осталось потратить до следующего уровня.
Возможно есть какой-то плагин для реализации задачи?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас WP, то лучше всего поищите подобные плагины, либо же записывайте в базу данных сколько человек потратил и далее работайте уже с этой суммой.